# Dynamically Build 'where' clause in Linq

Tags: c#, linq

I have a code which searches a data table for specific strings and returns back a subset of the entire datatable based on certain condition (unique id field). Sample code below which searches for "First" and "Employee" in a datatable and only returns those entries back which have same l_id value.

```
//Get all Id's that satisfy all conditions:            
List<int> results = dtResult.AsEnumerable()
    // Get all Id's:
    .Select(dataRow => dataRow.Field<int>("l_id"))
    // Filter the Id's : 
    .Where(id =>
        // the Id should be greater than one.
            id > 1
                // and the datatable rows with this Id should have a record with W_Text = First
            && dtResult.AsEnumerable().Any(dataRow => dataRow.Field<string>("W_Text") == "First" && dataRow.Field<int>("l_id") == id)
                // and the datatable rows with this Id should have a record with W_Text = Employee
            && dtResult.AsEnumerable().Any(dataRow => dataRow.Field<string>("W_Text") == "Employee" && dataRow.Field<int>("l_id") == id))
            .Distinct().ToList();

// Get all datatable rows filtered by the list of Id's.
dtCopy = dtResult.AsEnumerable().Where(dataRow => results.Contains((dataRow.Field<int>("l_id")))).CopyToDataTable();
```

Now if I have get the search text dynamically then how do I proceed with this? 
For. Eg, in the above code if I had to pass "First" as well as "Employee" as well as "salary" then how do i proceed?

How can I make this generic?

Thanks in advance for your assistance!

EDIT - Looks like I have not been clear in my post, so let me rephrase again

I have  a datatable which looks like this

```
l    |  t    |  r    |  b   |   x   |   y   |   w_text | l_id
-------------------------------------------------------------
70   |  314  |  141  |  328 |   1   |   5   |   First  | 4
149  |  318  |  194  |  328 |   2   |   5   |   Employe| 4
204  |  311  |  254  |  326 |   3   |   5   |   John   | 4
264  |  311  |  325  |  326 |   4   |   5   |   Smith  | 4
1924 |  310  |  2000 |  329 |   5   |   5   |   First  | 5
70   |  341  |  109  |  355 |   1   |   6   |   step   | 5
115  |  340  |  130  |  355 |   2   |   6   |   of     | 5
136  |  340  |  175  |  355 |   3   |   6   |   Linq   | 5
185  |  339  |  320  |  356 |   4   |   6   |   Last   | 6
70   |  394  |  101  |  411 |   1   |   8   |   Employe| 6
114  |  390  |  199  |  405 |   2   |   8   |   John   | 6
210  |  390  |  269  |  405 |   3   |   8   |   Doe    | 6
```

The only search criteria I have on my hand is 'W_Text'.So I would want to search for say the unique phrase "First Employee".Only one l_id (in this case l_id = 4) would have both the words "First" as well as "Employee".If i search "First" separately and "Employee" separately,then I would get a bigger data set which doesnt solve my purpose. My objective is to get the below unique dataset when i search"First Employee"

```
l    |  t    |  r    |  b   |   x   |   y   |   w_text | l_id
-------------------------------------------------------------
70   |  314  |  141  |  328 |   1   |   5   |   First  | 4
149  |  318  |  194  |  328 |   2   |   5   |   Employe| 4
204  |  311  |  254  |  326 |   3   |   5   |   John   | 4
264  |  311  |  325  |  326 |   4   |   5   |   Smith  | 4
```

In SQL terms, this is similar to

```
Select * From Table where l_id in (Select l_id from Table where W_Text in ('First','Employee') group by l_id having count(l_id) > 1)
```

The above code which I have mentioned (was helped by a good Samaritan) works perfectly fine and returns me the above dataset. The problem is that it works only with "First Employee". I am having trouble with searching say "First step of Linq". the search phrase is passed to the program at runtime and can be of how many  ever words. I have tried separating the Wheres but the 'having' condition misses and which is where the entire dataset again is returned.

Hence I request you all to kindly assist me with this problem. I am very new to Linq and am trying to work my way through. In the meantime, any help I can get would be highly appreciated. Thanks.

---EDIT got this working using this code (with someone's help)

```
 List<string> wTextFilter = new List<string>();

        foreach (string sf in strInputString.Split(' ')) //array by splitting on white space
        {
            wTextFilter.Add(sf);
        }

        // Get all Id's that satisfy all conditions:            
        List<int> results = dtResult.AsEnumerable()
            // Get all Id's:
            .Select(dataRow => dataRow.Field<int>("l_id"))
            // Filter the Id's : 
            .Where(id =>
                // the Id should be greater than one.
                    id > 1 &&
                        // check if all W_Text entries has a record in the datatable with the same Id.
                    wTextFilter.All(W_Text => dtResult.AsEnumerable().Any(dataRow => dataRow.Field<string>("W_Text") == W_Text && dataRow.Field<int>("l_id") == id)))
                    .Distinct().ToList();

        // Get all datatable rows filtered by the list of Id's.
        dtCopy = dtResult.AsEnumerable().Where(dataRow => results.Contains((dataRow.Field<int>("l_id")))).CopyToDataTable();
```

Comment: use your own logic man!

Comment: Not quite sure what you need, but you can chain the Where calls, like `.Where(condition1).Where(condition2)` and so on.

Comment: Thanks mate, for the advice. I'm unable to crack it, hence came for expert advice!

Comment: your query seems incorrect. https://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/dynamic-linq-part-1-using-the-linq-dynamic-query-library

Comment: do you use the result in a DataGridView control?

Comment: Query is correct and giving me a response actually. I have added more details in OP. Please take a look if you get a chance. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Few problems with your code:

1. You're selecting the ID *before* you've filtered. This means you end up with a collection of `int`s, meaning you can't then filter by another column. You should filter *then* select the required columns
2. You don't need the final check to see if the column `l_id`. We've already checked that `l_id == id`, so obviously the column exists
3. Your currently query is incorrect. You're returning the row if *any* row in the dataset matches:

```
dtResult.AsEnumerable().Any(dataRow => dataRow.Field<string>("W_Text") == "First" && dataRow.Field<int>("l_id") == id)
```

This says, for every row, check if there are *any* rows which match. If so, return that row. Your query will either return the entire dataset, or nothing.

You can chain `.Where()` clauses. For example:

```
public List<int> DoIt(int id, params string[] searchFor)
{
    var results = dtResult.AsEnumerable()       
        // Filter the Id's : 
        .Where(dr => dr.id > 1)
        .Where(dr => dr.Field<int>("l_id") == id);

    foreach (var sf in searchFor)
        results = results.Where(dr => dr.Field<string>("W_Text") == sf);

    results = results.Select(dataRow => dataRow.Field<int>("l_id"))

    return results.Distinct().CopyToDataTable();
}
```

Comment: Rob. Thanks for your response. I think I was not clear in what I wanted. I have added an Edit on the OP. Please can you take a look? Thanks

The thing is I am losing out on the result set if I do not use the && which is crucial in this case

Comment: Can you merge two Where together? Say `.Where(dr => dr.id > 1 && dr => dr.Field<int>("l_id") == id)`.

Answer (score 1):

Start with your base clause:

```
results = results.Where(id => id > 1);
```

Then dynamically add clauses as needed:

```
if (/**some condition**/)
    results = results.Where(id => dtResult.AsEnumerable().Any(dataRow => dataRow.Field<string>("W_Text") == "First" && dataRow.Field<int>("l_id") == id));
if (/**another condition**/)
    results = results.Where(id => dtResult.AsEnumerable().Any(dataRow => dataRow.Field<string>("W_Text") == "Employee" && dataRow.Field<int>("l_id") == id))
```

and so on.  For each condition you want to dynamically add, add a new `.Where()` clause.  You can chain as many of these as you like, and logically it would be the same as a series of `&&` clauses in a single `.Where()`.

Comment: David - . Thanks for your response. I think I was not clear in what I wanted. I have added an Edit on the OP. Please can you take a look? Thanks

The thing is I am losing out on the result set if I do not use the && which is crucial in this case

Answer (score 0):

Here is something closer to your SQL subquery:

```
var q = dtResult.AsEnumerable()                                    // from Table 
  .Where(r => new[] { "First", "Employee" }.Contains(r["W_Text"])) // where W_Text in ('First','Employee')
  .GroupBy(r => (int)r["l_id"])                                    // group by l_id
  .Where(g => g.Count() > 1)                                       // having count(l_id) > 1
  .Select(g => g.Key);                                             // Select l_id
```

and here is a bit more efficient version:

```
var words = new HashSet<string> { "First", "Employee" };  // optional HashSet instead of List for a bit faster .Contains

int iId = dtResult.Columns.IndexOf("l_id");
int iText = dtResult.Columns.IndexOf("W_Text");

var iRows = dtResult.Rows.Cast<DataRow>(); // a bit faster than dtResult.AsEnumerable()

var results = new HashSet<int>(  // optional HashSet instead of List for faster .Contains
        iRows
        .Where(r => words.Contains(r[iText]))    // filter the rows that contain the words
        .ToLookup(r => (int)r[iId])              // group by l_id
        .Where(g => g.Count() >= words.Count)    // filter the groups that contain all words
        .Select(g => g.Key)                      // select l_id
    );

var dtCopy = iRows.Where(r => results.Contains((int)r[iId])).CopyToDataTable(); // InvalidOperationException if no DataRows
```

---

but if all the data is already in a DataTable, then you can just group by `l_id` and get the groups that contain all of the words:

```
string[] words = { "First", "Employee" }; 

int iId = dtResult.Columns.IndexOf("l_id");
int iText = dtResult.Columns.IndexOf("W_Text");

var iRows = dtResult.Rows.Cast<DataRow>(); 

var idGroups = iRows.ToLookup(r => (int)r[iId]);    // group by id

var result = idGroups.Where(g => !words.Except(g.Select(r => r[iText] as string)).Any());

var dtCopy = result.SelectMany(g => g).CopyToDataTable();
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. I appreciate it. Let me try and get back soon.

p.s. I have edited the OP with a solution that is working for me. However, I will try yours and get back as well. Thanks again!